# C++ Program for Finding LCM of given N number

Tags: c++, asp.net, c

i want to find LCM of more than two numbers

C++   Program for Finding LCM of given N number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int lcm(int a, int b) { return (a/gcd(a,b))*b; }
```

For `gcd` look at [Euclid algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations).
For more than 2 numbers use `lcm` iteratively on the next number and the result of the previous. In code:

```
int lcms(int l int * a)
{
        int     i, result;
        result = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) result = lcm(result, a[i]);
        return result;
}
```

Comment: This is for two numbers, a and b. How does this help the original poster who specifically asked 'I want to find LCM of more than two numbers'?

Comment: Ah, I missed the more than two. I added a generalization.

Comment: you are using an uninitialized stack variable `result`, also we need to send the first and second element that is `a[0]` and `a[1]`, so the loop should start from **1** and go up to **n**. and `result` should be initialized with `a[0]`. good work by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Store your N numbers in an integer pointer and call recursively a method that found the LCM.
If you know how big is N you can do it with a cycle.
As overcitated you can use:

```
int lcm(int a, int b) { return (a/gcd(a,b))*b; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The basis for this answer is

**num1 * num2 = lcm(num1, num2) * gcd(num1, num2)**
so the code in my opinion should go like this

```
int gcd(int num1, int num2){

    while(num1 != num2){
        if(num1 > num2)
            num1 -= num2;
        else
            num2 -= num1;
    }
    return num1;
}

int lcm(int num1, int num2){
    return (num1/gcd(num1, num2))*num2;  // as mentioned by Bryan above.
}

int main(void){

    int i =0, result = 1;

    for(i=2 ;i<=n; i++){ // n is the upper limit
                         // be sure to check limits of data types.

        result= lcm(result, i);
    }
 // print the result;

    return 0;
}
```

I just reframed the answer given by bryan, i was solving problem5 of project-euler, thought of improvising on the answer. :)